# How to resolve this CORS issue ? (.NET Web API)

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have a .NET Core Web API running on http://localhost:5001.
I am calling these service from another web app (Which is running on http://localhost:5004)
and I got the error in browser:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 405.
```

I put below code in Startup.cs in Web API

```
    app.UseCors(
          options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5004/", "https://localhost:5004/").AllowAnyMethod()
     );
```

This time also error occurred but code is 205.

Third time I ran with removing '/' in options:

```
app.UseCors(
      options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5004", "https://localhost:5004").AllowAnyMethod()
 );
```

Error remains, but this time there was no status code.

Comment: Origins typically don't have a `/` at the end, so I find that suspicious. It's possible your framework strips does, but not every language does.

Comment: @Evert, sorry I edited the error message. the slash was not there

Comment: My comment was about the list of origins in your code snippet, not the url in your error!

Comment: Actually I removed them also and run, the error remains. But this time no status code there :)

Comment: Then I would suggest to fully update your question with the new situation. The title was presumably also wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a look at the docs, all their examples are placing the rules in the AddCors method, not the UseCors method.

So instead of

```
app.UseCors(
  options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5004", "https://localhost:5004").AllowAnyMethod()
 );
```

try the following

```
string myPolicy = "my_policy";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options=>{
    options.AddPolicy(myPolicy,policy=>{
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5004", "https://localhost:5004");
    });
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(myPolicy);
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score -1):

use this. you also have to put last condition. `AllowAnyHeader`.

```
  app.UseCors(
  options => options
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5004", "https://localhost:5004")
                .AllowAnyMethod().
                .AllowAnyHeader());
```

Answer (score -1):

Configuration in **Startup.cs** till .net Core 5. From 6 onwards in **Program.cs**

Add following in **ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5005",
                                    "https://localhost:5000",
                                    "https://localhost:3011",
                                    "http://localhost:3011")
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

add following in **Configure**

```
app.UseCors();
```